# JavaScript - custom Google Sign In has to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin

This is the HTML:

```
            <div id="button_google_login" class="customGPlusSignIn" onclick="startApp();">
                <span class="dont_close" style="padding-left: 12px;">Sign In with Google</span>
            </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
  var googleUser = {};
  var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: '[Secret].apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        //scope: 'additional_scope'
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('button_google_login'));
    });
  };

  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
              var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
              console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
              console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
              console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
              console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
        }, function(error) {
          // error or break up
        });
  }
```

I need to click the button twice to start the Sign In process, what could be the problem? I also tried the normal non custom version and it worked how it should.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all I don't recommend posting your client_id to a public audience.

Comment: on clicking, you then `attachSignin(document.getElementById('button_google_login'));` which adds a click handler ... so yeah ... two clicks would be required

Comment: @TomMarienfeld why? The visitors can see it by observing the source code anyway, it can't be hidden, or can it?

Comment: @JaromandaX this is just the code I copied from google tutorial for custom button, I don't understand what exactly it does and it's way more complicated than facebook login

Comment: This is not exactly the copied code from the google tutorial, since you are missing to call startApp() when the document has loaded, like explained in my answer.

Comment: You can Google oauth button from EHTML: https://github.com/Guseyn/EHTML#simple-e-google-oauth-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you copied the example from [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button). There the `startApp()` function is called at the end of the body Tag. Therefore the click handler to the Google button is assigned, when the document has loaded. You changed the behaviour insofar as that the click handler is only assigned, when somebody clicks the button. Because of that, you have to click that button two times.

Why don't you want to do it like in the Google provided example?

Simply add `<script>startApp();</script>` before the closing `</body>` Tag and remove the `onclick="startApp();` attribute from your button.

Comment: I don't understand why it works by removing onclick from the button but it does, thanks :D

Comment: Not before, I added it now. At first I thought the sign in will be called instantly this way when page is loaded so I removed it and added onclick to button

Answer (score 1):

I would to a `onClick` event on a btn and then call a `login` function

```
function login() {
              var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
              console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
              console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
              console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
              console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}
```

Comment: This looks like the nomal way to do it without custom button but how exactly can I do it in my case?